# Extract values from raster from list of text file of coordinates in r

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r

I have several raster files that i am trying to extract values from that come from some lat longs found in a text file. I've been successful with `raster::extract` in the past but seem to be running into a new problem here. The `extract` function returns NAs despite the projections seeming to line up.

Here is an (almost) reproducible example that shows my issue.

```
#reproducable example for SO
#
library(leaflet)
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
testRast <- raster("FranceRasters/FRA_STU_EU_S_CLAY.rst")
# crs string for ETRS89
crs(testRast) <- "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"

testRast
# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 1109, 1076, 1193284  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
# extent      : 3209000, 4285000, 2026000, 3135000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
# data source : D:\GIS\STU_EU_Layers\FranceRasters\FRA_STU_EU_S_CLAY.rst 
# names       : FRA_STU_EU_S_CLAY 
# values      : 0, 61  (min, max)

#Small sample of lat ongs that need sampling
Coordinate.sample <-  structure(list(Longitude = c(7.62648877, 7.63023291, 7.37533534, 
                                                   7.37484746, 7.59758433, 7.46470834, 7.46133708, 7.46632616, 7.45291197, 
                                                   7.52007514), Latitude = c(48.56788166, 48.59294834, 48.65367653, 
                                                                             48.65288703, 48.78729009, 48.71844903, 48.71878129, 48.71828592, 
                                                                             48.71898041, 48.52164554)), .Names = c("Longitude", "Latitude"
                                                                             ), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

#convert to spatial points
Coordinate.sample <- SpatialPoints(Coordinate.sample)

projection(Coordinate.sample) <- projection(testRast)
#show projections line up
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addRasterImage(testRast) %>% addCircleMarkers(data=Coordinate.sample)

#extraction leads to NAs
raster::extract(testRast,Coordinate.sample)
      [,1]
 [1,]   NA
 [2,]   NA
 [3,]   NA
 [4,]   NA
 [5,]   NA
 [6,]   NA
 [7,]   NA
 [8,]   NA
 [9,]   NA
[10,]   NA
```

As you can see the extraction has failed. Does anyone have any ideas why it has failed?

Here is an image of the `leaflet()` output to show that the coords and raster are in the right projection.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting the projection of `Coordinate.sample` instead of transforming it.

First set the original coordinate system when creating SpatialPoints, in this case it seems to be WGS84:

```
Coordinate.sample <- SpatialPoints(Coordinate.sample, proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
```

and then change the line

```
projection(Coordinate.sample) <- projection(testRast)
```

to

```
Coordinate.sample <- spTransform(Coordinate.sample, CRS("+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"))
```

and it should work. This will transform your coordinates to the specified projection.

Comment: Hi Janina, running your suggestion gives me the error `No transformation possible from NA reference system`

Comment: @MichaelBird Oh, sorry, I didn't realise that the coordinate system wasn't set in the first place. Give me a minute and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @MichaelBird Edited.

Comment: Wonderful, that's working perfectly now. Thank you very much!